# enforce ng-pattern before submit and not during manipulation

Tags: angularjs

Currently I use   `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})$/"`
to enfore a float input with exactly 2 decimals.

problem:
user input is beeing validated immediately and not only after trying to submit.
how can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody finds himself in a similar topic..
It's possible to delay model update and validation
see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-model-update-triggers
be aware that this has serious side effects.
you should perform your controller action also delayed (usinge timeout in combination with form.$valid check) in order to prevent continuing with invalid form data...